# Facebook FQL public post search by keyword

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, search, facebook-fql

I'm trying to accomplish something similar to the graph link below; however, I would like it to be in FQL form. I've been exploring and trying to figure it out how to accomplish this; consequently, I've failed miserably.

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q={insert keyword}&type=post

Comment: Nor FQL or Graph API will help you getting public objects. Only the public Graph API **Search** is purposed to do that. Keep using it!

Answer (score 1):

FQL has gone out of use as of version 2.0.
What you are looking for seems like a google search and it can not be done via the api.
If you looking for something on your own profile write something to read and then parse the value.
You can not run it on the whole of Facebook.